# Bootstrap-3-Typeahead not working in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using bootstrap version3.3.5 with bootstrap-3-typeahead. Typeahead is working fine in firefox but not working in chrome. I get Uncaught typeerror: "TypeError: $(...)typeahead is not a function". I am using django framework. Typeahead.js is included in bootstrap.js file using grunt.

I found while browsing that it can happen because of following reasons:-

1. jQuery is loaded after bootstrap.js.
2. jQuery is being loaded more than once.

But both of these does not seem to hold true for my code .Code is as following:-

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" %}">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

/*
rest of html .. No JS or Jquery is getting loaded in between.
*/

```
    <script src="{% static "jquery/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{% static "bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#id_area').typeahead({
                source: function (query, process) {
                    return $.get('/user/match/area/?q=' + query, function (data) {
                        return process(data.search_results);
                    });
                }
            });
            function customwidth()
            {
                var formwidth = $('#adv-search').width();       
                $('.dropdown-menu').width(formwidth- 40);   
            };

            customwidth();
            $(window).resize(function(e) {
                customwidth();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The error I am getting on line -- $('#id_area').typeahead({ . I am not able to figure out what is the issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what had gone wrong. But after clearing the browser cache (ctrl+F5) , it started worked fine.

If anyone knows what could have been gone wrong, please let me know. This might help me in future.